# Is this simple proposed scheme semantically secure?

Tags: security-definition, semantic-security

Suppose we have two parties, including $P_1$ and $P_2$ using a type of symmetric encryption algorithm, say, AES256. Let's assume the shared key is: $K$.

Encryption: 
Each party generate a key such that:

Initialization: $c=1$

Key generation: $K_{new} =  K + c$ and $c = c + 1$.

For encryption: For every message do: $Enc_{K_{new}}(message)$

Decryption: The same rule applies to it.

For decryption: $Dec_{K_{new}}(message)$

Would this proposed scheme secure if we make use of the last bits of the generated key, say the last 16 bits?

Comment: What mode of AES? Sounds kinda like CTR, where you encrypt the key and counter to get a keystream, and then XOR this with the message.

Comment: @SamG101 I don't know if does the mode of AES change the answer to my question?! Let's assume ECB mode.

Comment: This looks like you are trying to construct a counter-in-tweak like mode of operation.

Comment: @SEJPM Is it semantically secure?

Comment: @ SEJPM Would this proposed scheme secure if we make use of the last bits of the generated key, say the last 16 bits?

Comment: Surely almost the same key is being used for multiple encryption. If the mode is a stream cipher, then there is a problem, check out the "same key and nonce for ctr attack", but for a block cipher mode, it should be ok, but why change the key per message if you are using a block cipher anyways with a random iv or counter

Comment: The problem of this scheme is that it uses related keys for its queries. So _intuitively_ I'd say that it likely is secure if the block cipher is $+$-rk-prp-secure. But related-key security is a really strong assumption and AES is notorious for being weak in this regard.